# Validate database schema in Hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, validation, database-schema

Hibernate [4.x](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#validateSchema(org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect,%20org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata)) and [3.x](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#validateSchema(org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect,%20org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata)) has method `Configuration#validateSchema` that allows to verify that current database schema matches the object model. However the method is missing in version 5. How the database schema can be validated in Hibernate 5?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality was extracted and is accessible through interface [SchemaValidator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/SchemaValidator.html).